# Как использовать FOSOAuthServerBundle в symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony2, oauth2

Начал открывать для себя symfony2. Решил прикрутить oAuth2 (FOSOAuthServerBundle), сделал всё по [доке](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).
Подскажите как это использовать на примере авторизации (использую стандартную авторизацию symfony, без сторонних бандлов).

Comment: Вот [отличная статья](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/07/19/oauth2-explained-part-3-using-oauth2-bare-hands/) в одной из частей которой присутствуют примеры использования. Так же там описаны возможности расширения бандла под свои нужды.

Comment: @m9_psy, на международном stackoverflow подобных [проблем нет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755481/how-to-configure-fosuserbundle-to-be-the-authentication-provider-for-my-fosoauth)

Comment: Полезная статейка, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Gedweb, это повод флагнуть ответ на *международном stackoverflow*